# Is it possible to create a database link between an Oracle Express 11g database to a SQL Server or do I need full 11g?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to create a database link between an Oracle Express 11g database to a SQL Server Database? I've succeeded in getting the connection to work the other way around but I wasn't sure if this is possible with the express edition or whether I'd need the full blown 11g installation.

Comment: Yes.  Assuming you are using Generic Connectivity (ODBC), the express edition has the same functionality as the enterprise edition.

Comment: Turns out that this isn't the case according to the license agreement (the section on integration in particular) https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [license agreement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC115) it appears that you cannot do so (see the section on integration features which are not included in particular)

Comment: I don't follow you.  In the documentation you linked to, Database Gateway for ODBC is listed as a Yes.  So if you are using Generic Connectivity (ODBC), you can create the database link to a non-Oracle database.  You can't use the more sophisticated Transparent Gateways but those are extra cost options if you have the enterprise edition.